# Application Failed to Start Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have one framework using Spring Boot which contains a controller `RestController` class ,

```
@RequestMapping("/details")
@RestController
public class DataController {
    private KafkaStreams kafkaStreams;

    public DataController(KafkaStreams kafkaStreams) {
        this.kafkaStreams = kafkaStreams;
    }

    @Autowired
    DataService dataService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "getAllDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public boolean getAllDetails(KafkaStreams kafkaStreams) {
        return ktableService.getAllDetails(kafkaStreams);
    }
}
```

In my service implementation class I am using this `kafkaStreams` object to find the details for my different services.

Now I am using this framework as a dependency in my one of the other application where I have a runner class,

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
@Component
public class PipelineRunner {
    private final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private final SerdesExt serdesExt;

    @Autowired
    public PipelineRunner(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, SerdesExt serdesExt) {
        this.streamsBuilder = streamsBuilder;
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
        this.serdesExt = serdesExt;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void run() {
        ReflectData.AllowNull.get().addStringable(Utf8.class);
        ReflectData.get().addStringable(Utf8.class);
        DataProcessor processor = new DataProcessor(streamsBuilder, kafkaProperties,
                serdesExt);
        start();
    }

    private void start() {
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(),
                kafkaProperties.getKafkaStreamsProperties(serdesExt));
        System.out.println("----Its is started----");
        DataController controller = new DataController(kafkaStreams);
        kafkaStreams.start();

    }
}
```

In this class i am trying to create the object for `DataController` .

So when I am trying to run the application class,

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "framework package" })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am getting this error,

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in frameworkpackage.controllers.DataController required a bean of type 'org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams' in your configuration.
```

I am new to Spring Boot. So I might be doing something wrong here. If more info is needed I can provide.

> UPDATE

My pom file,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <confluent.version>4.1.0</confluent.version>
        <kafka.version>1.1.0</kafka.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.0</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-avro</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you add Kafka Streams `spring boot starter` dependency? Updating question with `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` would give more insight.

Comment: @BranislavLazic added the pom file

Comment: I'm unaware about how to configure Kafka with Spring boot but I think your `private KafkaStreams kafkaStreams;` should be autowired or injected in your constructor (based on your logs)

Comment: @MickaëlB Yup. I thought that Spring Boot would autoconfigure it. But nope. Seems like he will have to define `KafkaStreams` bean manually.

Comment: @MickaëlB I tried adding Autowired in 
 private KafkaStreams kafkaStreams; but facing the same issue

Comment: @Justin If you're trying to autowire `KafkaStreams`, you have to declare this bean somewhere. I think it should be your `kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(),
                kafkaProperties.getKafkaStreamsProperties(serdesExt));` or something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem is that you are trying to use a bean **kafkaStreams** in your class DataController, but there is no bean with this name in Spring context. You need to create it manually, so you can autowire it later.

In your case I would suggest to update PipelineRunner.java like this:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PipelineRunner
{
    private final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private final SerdesExt serdesExt;


    @Autowired
    public PipelineRunner(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder, KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, SerdesExt serdesExt)
    {
        this.streamsBuilder = streamsBuilder;
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
        this.serdesExt = serdesExt;
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void run()
    {
        ReflectData.AllowNull.get().addStringable(Utf8.class);
        ReflectData.get().addStringable(Utf8.class);
        DataProcessor processor = new DataProcessor(streamsBuilder, kafkaProperties,
            serdesExt);
        start();
    }


    @Bean
    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams()
    {
        KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(
            streamsBuilder.build(),
            kafkaProperties.getKafkaStreamsProperties(serdesExt));
        System.out.println("----Its is started----");
        kafkaStreams.start();
        return kafkaStreams;
    }
}
```

You dont need to create an instance of DataController by yourself, this will be done automatically by Spring.

More information about Spring approach to beans is available [there](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18579463)